# Not the same result between SqLite and MariaDb SELECT

Tags: mysql, sqlite, mariadb, sqlite-net, groupwise-maximum

I have 2 tables on Debian server, rides and steps.

From a Xamarin app I get data from this server ([Refit](https://github.com/paulcbetts/refit), [Newtonsoft Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) and [SQLite-net PCL](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) packages) to populate local tables.

When I use this query on mariadb:

```
SELECT 1_steps.* 
FROM   1_rides, 1_steps 
WHERE  1_rides.id=1_steps.ride_id 
   AND 1_rides.start=1 
GROUP BY 1_rides.id
```

I got correct results (**first** step of each ride, then it starts with 1)

But when use equivalent for SqLite:

```
SELECT Steps.* 
FROM   Rides,Steps 
WHERE  Rides.Id=Steps.RideId 
   AND Rides.Start=1
GROUP BY Rides.Id
```

In the result, I get the **last** step of each (same) ride!

Whether on mariadb or sqlite, each table has a primary key (`id` field).
I checked, the data is sent, received and saved in the same order.

Simply added in mobile app with:

```
foreach (var step in await App.RestClient.getSteps())  
    if (dbCon.InsertOrReplace(step) != 1)  
    ....
```

I tried adding `ORDER BY Rides.Id` but that does not change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are relying on something that is not allowed by strict SQL standards: whenever you have a `group by` clause, the fields in the `select` clause must either appear in the `group by` clause as well, or must be aggregations (e.g. `min`, `count`), or must be functionally dependent on the `group by` fields.

In your case those conditions are not met and so if the DB engine allows this, it will have to decide which value to pick within a same group: the first, the last, or still something else.

The way to deal with this, is to be explicit what you want to get in such a case, by specifying an aggregation:

```
SELECT     1_steps.id,
           min(1_steps.step),
           max(1_steps.whatever),
           avg(1_steps.some_number),
FROM       1_rides
INNER JOIN 1_steps
        ON 1_rides.id=1_steps.ride_id 
WHERE      1_rides.start=1 
GROUP BY   1_rides.id
```

You did not specify the fields of your table, but the idea should be clear: list the fields separately (not `*`), and apply the type of aggregation to them you need.

#### Alternative

If you are not interested in aggregating anything, but just want one particular record from `steps` per ride, then don't use `group by`, but specify the condition that filters exactly that one record from `steps`:

```
SELECT     1_steps.*
FROM       1_rides
INNER JOIN 1_steps
        ON 1_rides.id=1_steps.ride_id 
WHERE      1_rides.start=1
       AND 1_steps.step = 1 
ORDER BY   1_rides.id
```

Note the condition `1_steps.step = 1`: you'll have to decide what that condition should be of course.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation :) Fast and complete. I opted for the first solution that works perfectly :)